# Trying to get the latest ID and one unique name from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the `Sectionname` and `SectionId` from `SectionNomination` table. I need to combine the `SectionId` to get the last section and only one `SectionName`.

So from this table:

[image]

I need to get one `testSection1` and one `TestSection3` with one `section ID` which is 35. Same thing with `TestSection3`, I want to get `sectionID = 37`.

I wrote this query to achieve this:

```
select  
    SectionName, SectionId
from 
    testTable pt, 
    (select max(SectionId) as pID 
     from testTable 
     group by SectionID) st
where 
    pt.SectionID = st.pID
```

This is not returning the max ID and also returning the duplicates.

Here is the sample data:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[testTable] ([SectionName])
VALUES ('TestSection1')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[testTable] ([SectionName])
VALUES ('TestSection2')
```

`sectionId` is an Identity column.

Create table is this SQL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testTable]
(
    [SectionID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SectionName] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    
    CONSTRAINT [PK_SectionNomination] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SectionID] ASC)
)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is `SectionName` nullable? And why does it permit 1000-char strings?

Comment: The problem is you're doing an `INNER JOIN` on _every_ row because `select max(SectionId) as pID from testTable group by SectionID ` returns every row...

Comment: Please do not use images, use tabular text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is...

```
SELECT
    s.SectionName,
    MAX( s.SectionId ) AS MaxSectionId
FROM
    dbo.TestTable AS s
GROUP BY
    s.SectionName
ORDER BY
    SectionName;
```

| SectionName | MaxSectionId |
| --- | --- |
| TestSection1 | 35 |
| TestSection3 | 37 |
| TestSection4 | 38 |

---

[DbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/y88-gXDe)

Comment: OP was not entirely clear, however their desired output seems to not be interested in rows that do not have multiple sectionID values. I added a having clause above to account for it.

Comment: @ClearlyClueless - The original posted query made no attempt to exclude singletons, so it appears that the OP intended to include one row for each SectionName. (Other than old-style joins, the only real bug in that original query was the wrong group-by column.)